# Composer doesn't find class...but find the sibling file

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have a folder structure which I know is fine, because it works...for the most part.

Have a look at these 2 headers:

```
namespace Library\GitHubClient\Client\Services;

use Library\GitHubClient\Client\GitHubClient;
use Library\GitHubClient\Client\GitHubService;
use Library\GitHubClient\Client\Objects\GitHubTeam;
use Library\GitHubClient\Client\Objects\GitHubFullTeam;
use Library\GitHubClient\Client\Objects\GitHubUser;
use Library\GitHubClient\Client\Objects\GitHubRepo;

class GitHubOrgsTeams extends GitHubService {
```

and

```
namespace Library\GitHubClient\Client\Services;

use Library\GitHubClient\Client\GitHubClient;
use Library\GitHubClient\Client\GitHubService;

class GithubOrgsRepos extends GitHubService {
```

The first file, composer autoloads without issue, but the 2nd it cannot find. The head-scratcher is: they both live in the same folder.

In fact, as you can see from this parent constructor, there are 3 classes that live in the same folder, and only the first 2 autoload.

```
public function __construct(GitHubClient $client) {
    parent::__construct($client);

    $this->members = new GitHubOrgsMembers($client);
    $this->teams = new GitHubOrgsTeams($client);
    $this->repos = new GithubOrgsRepos($client);
}
```

Does composer suffer some kind of limiting issue?

Comment: OK, I can answer the end question myself...no! I moved that line up 2 and it still fails

Comment: whats the error your getting?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `composer.json` and the full file path to your class files.

Comment: I can notice one tiny difference: `GitHubOrgsTeams` and `GithubOrgsRepos`. One has a capital H for Hub, the other one has not.

Comment: @Arcesilas Thank you! That's all it was. If you want to add that as an answer I'll select it. Too many hours staring at code today, and something silly like that got me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As suggested in your comment, here's an answer you may accept.

These two lines help notice what is probably a typo:

```
    $this->teams = new GitHubOrgsTeams($client);
    $this->repos = new GithubOrgsRepos($client);
```

The first one has a capital H for hub, not the second one.

It's likely you either mistyped the class name or the filename.

Answer (score 0):

There are three places that I stuff this up all the time:

- A typo in the filename (such as an incorrectly capitalised letter on a case sensitive filesystem)
- The autoloader is cached; run `composer dump-autoload` for it to re-build the autoloader.
- Less common: you're using a file loader and not PSR, and the file needs to be added to composer.json manually.

The last thing to check is that your calling code (in the constructor) definitely has the `use Library\GitHubClient\Client\Services\GithubOrgsRepos;` statement at the top.